# DCOMCNFG: why doesn't dll show up?

Tags: dll, dcom

I have a COM DLL that I registered via RegSvr32 but it does not show up in DComCnfg.

Any help as to why?

I think I am missing a few registry keys, but I do not understand why I would, i thought RegSvr32 did that for me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regsvr32 merely runs the registration function your DLL exposes. If the registration info in your DLL is wrong, regsvr32 can do nothing about it. If you're not sure what to look for, you can try running Regmon (by sysinternals) with the filter set to *regsvr32* or so, and then look for the GUIDs that have been registered. Then look for them in the details view of DCOMCNFG. You will probably find it there if regsvr32 succeeded. This will give you an idea about the root of the problem, though the actual solution depends on what's wrong in your registration info.

Another remote option is that you have some 32-64 bit conflict, where regsvr32 is run in 32 bit and DCOMCNFG in 64 bit or vice versa. I'm not sure what DCOMCNFG shows in such case - I never had this problem, but there are different registry hives for 32 and 64 bits, and perhaps you're not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

**Applies to most 32 bit COM applications**

- Install Server System Files to c:\Windows\SysWOW64
- Install .UDL files to c:\program Files (x86)\common files\system\OLE DB\Data Links\
- Install all application files to c:\program Files (x86)\…
- Install 32 Bit SQL Server 2005/2008 to c:\program Files (x86)\…

**Registering 32 bit COM applications via DCOMCNFG (DCOM Config)**

- Start… Run… mmc -32
- go to File → Add/Remove Snap-in and add "Component Services"
- The entries will be automatically added. Once the entries are added you can use the 64 bit DCOMCNFG again.

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative way to register 32 bit COM applications on a 64-bit server**

- Start...Run...C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mmc comexp.msc /32

As described here
[http://msdn.microsoft.com...dcomcnfg.exe_and_64-bit_applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678426%28VS.85%29.aspx#dcomcnfg.exe_and_64-bit_applications)